# Proper Linux environment for php5.3?

Tags: linux, centos, php53, pdo

I use CentOS 5.5 64bits, and I'd strongly prefer running php5.3 there (please focus on this), but if you have a safe recipe to run it on another distribution, I'll take it into consideration.

My problem is that I get to achieve either one of these two things:

- I install php5.3 (from here: http://www.webtatic.com/blog/2009/06/php-530-on-centos-5/) and everything works, but without PDO.
- I install everything from 'remi' repos (including their own MySQL version, because otherwise I'd get an incompatibility error while installing), but when it comes to the part of the script where I use PDO, I get a blank screen and it dies without leaving any errors (even with errors activated).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Install php-pdo(from 'remi' repos):

```
 yum install php-pdo
```

and restart web server. For test, use phpinfo() or php -i.

Comment: where he wrote that he install php-pdo?

Comment: Gah, my bad, morning blindness ;)